# Div id generating with php

Tags: smarty

I'm using smarty CMS so for adding php code i have to edit index.inc.php then i have to call that on from tpl file.. so what i need is 
Example at present it showing like this

```
<div id="div1"> ... </div>
<div id="div1"> ... </div>
<div id="div1"> ... </div>
<div id="div1"> ... </div>
<div id="div1"> ... </div>
```

same div1 id in all tags.. i need it to show like this

```
<div id="div1"> ... </div>
<div id="div2"> ... </div>
<div id="div3"> ... </div>
<div id="div4"> ... </div>
<div id="div5"> ... </div>
```

Please show me to generate id numbers from 1 to 5 through php i will try to implement it to smarty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use smarty's `{section}`:

```
{section name=divLoop loop=5} 
    <div id="div{$smarty.section.divLoop.iteration}">...</div>
{/section}
```

Full syntax documentation can be found here:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.section.tpl